# Get partition name and partition label on Windows 10 for GPT disks

Tags: partitioning, gpt, volume-label

How can I read both partition name and partition label, for a given drive with GPT partition table? I would like to do it on Windows 10. According to this post, both exist and are different on GPT (not MBR) drives:

[What is the difference between a name and a label in gparted?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/289477/what-is-the-difference-between-a-name-and-a-label-in-gparted)

Using commands or software with GUI, either way will do provided it works.

Comment: Are you hoping to read this in a scriptable way, or are manual/app-based methods OK? What are you planning on using this information for?

Comment: I believe you can run parted in Windows Subsystem for Linux. Haven't tested myself, but a brief search seems to indicate you can.

Comment: @music2myear either way with UI or commands will do.

Comment: Please add this information to your original post by using the EDIT button.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've found how to do it on Linux. No idea how to do it in Windows, it's a pain in the ass.

```
sudo lsblk -o name,fstype,mountpoint,label,partlabel,size
```

Answer (score 0):

`DISKPART` can show the label and name for GPT partitions using the `DETAIL` argument:

```
diskpart
select disk 0
select partition 1
detail partition
```

I believe that MS calls these differently though. Reading here (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/cd6eae06-fed7-4a12-a22c-bbab9ede3a42/set-gpt-labels-with-diskpart?forum=win10itprosetup) indicates that MS calls the Label "Type", and the Name "Label".

Comment: if the volume is bitlocker locked, "Label" shows nothing and "Type" shows Partition.


If I unlock the volume with the correct password, Label changes to the name you can change from "This PC". No trace of the GPT label, which should be displayed anyway even with locked volume.